# Where are the properties for custom control stored?

Tags: xpages

I know how to define the properties of a custom control on the design tab but I am not seeing them on the source tab.   Where are they stored?  If stored elsewhere, how do they get copied when I copy the custom control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the java perspective of your designer. Go to the custom controls directory and you will find xsp-config files. These files have the same name as the custon control they belong too

Comment: So I assume when the CC is copied, this file is also copied?

Comment: They're also visible in the Package Explorer. The xsp-config file contains all metadata about the Custom Control - properties, namespace and prefix, whether it shows in the palette, and Design Definition. You can add additional settings to properties there, which is what I did in the custom control in the Mobile Value Picker Project on OpenNTF